# остановка анимации

Tags: ios, objective-c, анимация

У меня есть view kartinka. При нажатии на экран картинка устремляется туда, крутится и меняет цвет на рандомный.

```
-(void)tapMetod:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tap{

[UIView animateWithDuration:TIME
                      delay:0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     self.kartinka.backgroundColor = [self randomColor];
                     self.kartinka.center = [tap locationInView:self.view];
                     self.kartinka.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
                     self.kartinka.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     NSLog(@"finish");
                 }];
}
```

Как можно поставить на паузу анимацию во время движения view. Именно поставить на паузу по среди пути, сохраняя ее угол наклона, цвет и положение на экране.

Answer (score 2):

Можно поставить на паузу весь слой. В приведенную ниже функцию подавайте слой картинки (`self.kartinka.layer`), либо, если на вашем view несколько таких анимаций у разных subview, подавайте в функцию слой самого верхнего view.

```
-(void)pauseLayer:(CALayer*)layer
{
  CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
  layer.speed = 0.0;
  layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
}

-(void)resumeLayer:(CALayer*)layer
{
  CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
  layer.speed = 1.0;
  layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
  layer.beginTime = 0.0;
  CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
  layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
}
```

Источник: Apple Technical QA1673

Comment: как я понимаю метод для воспроизведения анимации будет -(void)playLayer:(CALayer*)layer
{
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
    layer.speed = 1;
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
}. Если так то координаты вью все равно запоминаются в точке [tap locationInView:self.view] до которой она не успела дойти. Есть способ перезаписать координаты именно в той точке где она остановилась??